# How to use max on sum in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I am working in a task and got stuck at particular question. I am new to SQL so I am reaching out to this platform for the support. Below are the 2 tables. 1st is Theatre_play_table and 2nd is Ticketsales table.
**Question: List titles, directors and writers of all shows/plays with the highest total sale.**

Theatre_play_table

[image]

Ticketsales table

[image]

I have pasted screenshot of some part of the table. ID column in both the table represents the same information. Last column in Ticketsales table is Totalamount.

I have tried with below query;
Select theatre_play.title, theatre_play.director, theatre_play.writer, sum(totalamount)
from theatre_play, totalsales
where theatre_play.id = totalsales.id
group by theatre_play.title, theatre_play.director, Theatre_play.writer
order by sum(totalamount) desc
fetch first 3 rows only;

The above approach is not useful when data is huge. I wanted to apply max(sum(totalamount)) but oracle threw an error.

Can anyone please help me solve this question?

Comment: Your solution looks pretty good to me!

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it works but I wanted to use max function here but failed to apply.

Comment: Move aggregation of sales (by `play_id`) into the subquery and use `fetch first 1 rows with ties`, which will return all top-sold shows. Then perform a join. If you will provide sample data as text, I will be able to write a query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, the issue is to get the three highest values?
Then try something like this:

```
select * from (
 Select dpro.title, dpro.director, dpro.writer, sum(fth.totalamount) 
 from dpro
 join  fth on dpro.id = fth.id 
  
 group by dpro.title, dpro.director, dpro.writer 
 order by sum(totalamount) desc )
where rownum <=3
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The task is to find the highest sales - not limited to no. of highest values. I used 3 based on the output. How can I make it for dynamic where all the highest values appear.

Comment: @Dhwanil you'd either remove the where clause to get all of them or adjust it for the number of values

Comment: @SCCJS, So if I remove the where clause then all the values will appear.  In the above and earlier approach I looked at the data and then decided that there are only 3 highest values. This is not ideal when data is huge. The concern is to get only highest values without looking at the output. I hope this elaborates the questions.

Comment: @Dhwanil The query sorts the output beginning with the highest value. If you want all the values remove the where clause. If you want the 10 highest replace the 3 with a 10. You are saying that you want the "highest values". That, to me is, not very well defined. It implies that some are not qualifying and should not be viewed.

Comment: @Dhwanil when you say highest values, is that values equal to the highest? So if we have 100,100,100,10 it would return 100,100,100? Or are you wanting values greater than the average? Other than that we are just going to give you x number of values

Comment: @SCCJS, it should return only highest values. No limit to the number of instances.. so if we have 100,100,100,10 it would return 100,100,100 - yes